# How to hide this "close" button

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog

I am using this jquery-ui to display a dialog box but it comes with a freebee named as "close" which I don't want,

you can find rest of code here, [Why my Dialog box isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199779/why-my-dialog-box-isnt-working)

In html its coming up as

```
<a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span>
</a>
```

Comment: I can't find any function here to hide it, http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Why negative vote without explanation ?

Comment: See the [API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) under `Hiding the close button`.

Comment: @Boaz thanks, I was looking at wrong place

Comment: Because you didn't make much effort in solving problem by yourself, instead you are aksing a question that has been answered many times!

Comment: In your defense, it should be noted that the jQuery-UI documentation has never been reader-friendly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove close button on jQueryUI Dialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896777/remove-close-button-on-jqueryui-dialog)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you look at the documentation?

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

> Hiding the close button
>
> In some cases, you may want to hide the close button, for instance, if
>   you have a close button in the button pane. The best way to accomplish
>   this is via CSS. As an example, you can define a simple rule, such as:

```
.no-close .ui-dialog-titlebar-close { display: none; }
```

> Then, you can simply add the no-close class to any dialog in order to hide it's
>   close button:

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({   dialogClass: "no-close",   buttons: [
    {
      text: "OK",
      click: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    }   ] });
```

Comment: Now Dialog box not working at all, when I uncheck it nothing displays

Comment: should I add javaScript function in my handlethis() function ?